# How can I make a heart-shaped vector field emanating from a circle?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, vector-fields

How can I make a heart shaped vector field like the image below, the lines getting progressively straighter as they approach the x's center and y's max on the bottom of the circle and if the x = 0 and the y = 1 the curves are the curviest?
[image]

Comment: initially I thought it might be something like (1/y sin(x), 1/x sin(y) ), but since I'm without plotting software at the moment, I thought I'd try to reason it out. the sink would be at (0,- infinity).

Comment: On graph paper sketch it as accurately as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you should [check this one out.](https://xkcd.com/55/)

No but seriously, you can probably pose this as a differential equation with boundary conditions or an energy minimization. The boundary being the circle where points "outwards" at each point and outside the gradient should be minimized as well as increasing positive cost for absolute values of x:es for the vector field to deviate from [0,-1].

$$\min(v)\{|x|\cdot\|v-[0,-1]^t\| + \|\nabla v\| + c \|v-d\| \}$$

Where $v$ is the vector field we want to calculate, $c$ is the boundary mask for circle, $d$ is the vector pointing outwards at every point (radial vector). We may need to multiply with weights to get a good shape, I.e. noice curvature as compared to circle radius.

Comment: funny comic, what do I need to learn to understand your answer, I've only studied up to calculus III with Linear Algebra.

Comment: If you put the problem om some grid and approximate a solution numerically, then linear algebra and calculus should be enough. Maybe some "numerical methods" or "technical computations" could be good to know if you want implement a solver yourself. I am unsure if I can find the time to do it on my computer today, but I hope I can show some simulation later.

Comment: Awesome! If you happen to have sage or mat-lab, could you show me an equation to plot?